# correct preposition with the noun "contrast"

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition that goes with the noun form "contrast"? I know we can say there’s a contrast "between" two items. Is anything else acceptable? Here’s the sentence I'm working with:

> A resolution has been achieved, providing a clear contrast from where the journey started and now.

Is that okay? What about this: “... providing a clear contrast between the journey’s start and now.” Or maybe better: “ ... between the journey’s start and current phase.”

Comment: I'm a bit unclear about the question.  Is this what you are trying to say?   "A resolution has been achieved (or reached) as evidenced by the clear contrast between the journey's beginning and the journey now."

Comment: Contrast can take to, with, and of as well as between.  But the original sentence is confusing--is it a time comparison, a space comparison, or what?

Answer (score 1):

As far as *contrast* ***between*** goes, I would use phrasing similar to:

> A resolution has been achieved, providing a clear contrast between the journey's start and its end.

Or you can use *contrast* ***with***:

> Now that a resolution has been achieved, the journey's end stands in clear contrast with its start.

Or you can use *contrast* ***to***:

> With the achievement of a resolution, the end of the journey stands in clear contrast to its start.

---

Note that I am using *end*. If the journey is not actually finished, then I would suggest *current* ***state*** or *now*.

Also, I haven't incorporated your use of *where* into my examples—I don't know if geographical location is an important aspect of what you're trying to convey or not. If it is, consider *the* ***location*** *of the journey's start* and either *its final* ***destination*** or *its current* ***location***.

Hopefully this helps.